# How to seek position of currently played media

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i have found a way to control (play,pause, next, forward,...) currently played media playback using Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand").

But is there a way to seek a position ?

Answer (score -1):

This may work for you:

```
putLong("seekpos", x) // x is the Float you want to seek to
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does answer their question.. They have specifically asked "But is there a way to seek a position ?".. I have provided a solution to that question with `putLong("seekpos", x) // x is the Float you want to seek to` I'm not sure it can be answered any better than that..

Comment: i actually want to know how to tell the current music player to change position in the currently played track